# What is a workflow automation work where tasks have an unknown number of inputs?

Tags: python, automation, workflow, luigi

I am wanting to use something like Luigi or another Workflow automation suite. My problem is that I have nodes that have an unknown number of inputs. Luigi, for example, demands that you hard code the inputs ahead of time.

Let's say I have a graph where nodes represent Tasks and the lines all flow down and point from outputs to inputs of other tasks

```
  A
 / \
|   B
 \ /
  C
```

Where we start at A but flow down to B, then C, and C also accepts A's output.

I've found somethings like SciLuigi but it doesn't exactly solve my problem.

Comment: You have [Dynamic dependencies in Luigi](http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#dynamic-dependencies) (and here's [an example](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/examples/dynamic_requirements.py)). Besides that you should try to explain a little more how have you tried to write your Luigi tasks to solve your problem.

Comment: I did see that example but it doesn't quite fit my problem situation, either.

For an individual task, it can take in an arbitrary number of inputs but not sure from which other tasks or how many. All that matters are their outputs.

So far, I've worked with SciLuigi and other frameworks to see which might work. None of them match the ease of use of Luigi, other than this situation I have.

I've looked at creating a subclass for a special task that is then created by a factory and the special `run()` method is going to run a behavior instead. Not sure if it'll work out...

Answer (score 0):

The questions you need answer are: how does C know when to run? How do A and B know when to run? This is what goes into the `requires` method of the Luigi task. The Luigi model is a pull model, where each batch task decides when to run based on the completion of the tasks it is dependent upon. (It doesn't help to think of `A` or `B` "flowing down" to `C`)

In the simple model you show, `C` is the launch task of the pipeline. `C` will load (but not call `run`), and check to see if `A` and `B` are completed. If either of them is not completed, it will tell that subset to run. If they are already completed, or once they do complete, `C` will call `run`.  If task `A` and `B` only have work to do conditionally, their `complete` method can return `True` in the cases where they have no work to do. `C` can then `run`.

However, I am not sure that this is your particular issue. Perhaps you want `C` to run once for `A` and `C` to run once for `B`? In this sort of scenario I usually write the `run` method of `C` to operate on an arbitrary list of inputs (whether they be files in a directory, rows in a status database, or some other list of references). However, in this sort of case it is also sometimes better to just add whatever `C` does into the definition for `A` and `B`, perhaps defining a subclass of Task that adds in that post processing step provided by `C`.

In any case, there are many ways to run a pipeline, but it is difficult to suggest good alternatives at the extremely high level of abstraction that you describe. I find that switching your thinking to be a pull model is probably the first step to finding them.

Comment: What you describe in your first two paragraphs is what I think was going on. My situation is that I do know what A, B, and C are and when they should run. I want to use this to run machine learning models that people can change quickly. So let's say a user knows they want transformations on data, represented by A, B, and C but only change the hyper parameters around. Maybe they need to add another B data transformation from A to C again (so we get a diamond shaped graph) .

Ideally I want to hand a JSON/YML file describing known code modules and their relationships and just let it run.

Comment: My real issue is that at no time does any of A, B, C really know ahead of time who they depend on, so maybe pull based workflow automation like you describe isn't going to work for me.

Comment: What kind of machine learning models? Something like `Sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline`? I think the concept of Luigi evolved from the fact that trying to do pipelines in json/yml becomes overly complicated, as you trying to use them as a programming language.  See slides 23-26 here. https://www.slideshare.net/erikbern/luigi-presentation-nyc-data-science

Comment: That's an excellent resource, thanks!

My idea is that it'd be a cross between the two. Dependency graph can specify code that is already written, either pre-packaged or written by the user. Both the JSON graph and python/java/scala code gets uploaded. If you want to tune models, no code needed, just the json. If you need to do a new special transformation, then upload that, too, and make note of that in the dependency graph. I'm big on the JSON parts because I want to have a nice GUI make that part easy, too.

Comment: As for which models, it can be anything. Some code will be python, some will be java, some of it pytorch, some of it DL4J or who knows what else. :)

Comment: I think I see. I think what you might want to try in Luigi (at least to get started) is like three types of tasks. One family that reads input from various formats, one family of transformation type tasks, and one family of output type tasks to various sinks. You then have a `requires` method that reads from your definition file. I do think it will prove challenging to express some relationships, but with a common interchange format, it should be possible. Just a little complex to design in an SO comment thread! Good luck.